# Count in Mobile Service Azure

Tags: linq, azure, windows-phone, azure-mobile-services

I´m using a mobile service with Azure (for Windows Phone) and have queries like:

```
await App.MobileService.GetTable<MyTable>().Skip(1).Take(100).ToListAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    if (!t.IsFaulted)
                    {
                       //do something
                    }
                });
```

The question is, how could I know the total rows in the table "MyTable"? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `IncludeTotalCount()` when creating your queue, and once you do that, the result can be cast to the `ITotalCountProvider` interface, from which you can retrieve the total number of rows (which would match any filter option you passed; in your example since you didn't use any `Where` clauses, it would return the total number of records in the table).

```
c.GetTable<MyTable>().Skip(1).Take(100).IncludeTotalCount().ToListAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (!t.IsFaulted)
    {
        List<MyTable> results = t.Result;
        var totalCountProvider = (ITotalCountProvider)t.Result;
        var totalCount = totalCountProvider.TotalCount;
    }
});
```